# PHP7 built-in hash() function undefined

Tags: hash, undefined, php-7

I'm running PHP Version 7.0.5 and trying to use the hash function.

```
echo hash('sha256', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
```

The script returns the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hash()

The PHP docs indicate that the function should be included with PHP 7:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

> (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, **PHP 7**, PECL hash >= 1.1)

What am I missing?  How do I add the standard hash functions to my PHP 7 environment?

Comment: If you run `php -v` in the terminal, does it confirm the php version you expect that you're running?

Comment: Good idea!  -- Yes it does - PHP 7.0.5 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2016 01:26:54) ( NTS )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running PHP 7.2.34. Installing `php7-mod-hash` fixed it for me:

```sh
opkg update
opkg install php7-mod-hash
```